# How to make a function that sums the exponential's of a vector in R?

Tags: r, function

My professor has assigned a question for programming in R and I am stuck. He wants us to make a function that will take the exponential (e^(x[i]) of all the numbers in a vector and then sum them. the equation is:

the summation of e^x(i), n, and i=1.

I have made a function that will give me the exponential of the first value in my vector. But I want to get the exponential of all the values and sum them. Here is my code

```
 #Vector for summing
x=c(2,1,3,0.4)

#Code for function
mysum = 0

myfun=function(x){
for (i in 1:length(x)){
 mysum = mysum + exp(x[i])
 return(mysum)
}
}
myfun(x)

#returns 7.389056
```

I have also tried using i = 1:1 because the equation specifies i=1, even though I knew that would only go through 1 number, and it gave me the same answer.... obviously.

```
myfun=function(x){
for (i in 1:1)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to get it to sum?

Comment: A hint: What is the output of `sum(c(1, 2, 3, 4))`?

Comment: Put the return statement outside the loop. However, this is not how we do this in R. We like to use vectorization which makes the code much more readable and more performant. The `exp` function accepts a vector as input and we have a `sum` function in R. There is no need to write a loop.

Comment: And another hint: What is the output of `exp(c(1, 2, 3, 4))`

Comment: And a final, almost spoiler hint: What is the output of `sum(exp(c(1, 2, 3, 4)))` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You need to set the initial value of `mysum` to the accumulation afterwards, and also move the line `return(mysum)` outsides your `for` loop to return the result, i.e.,

```
myfun=function(x){
  mysum <- 0
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    mysum = mysum + exp(x[i])
  }
  return(mysum)
}
```

or just

```
myfun=function(x){
  mysum <- 0
  for (i in x){
    mysum = mysum + exp(x)
  }
  return(mysum)
}
```

- Since `exp` operation is vectoroized, you can also define your function `myfun` like below

```
myfun <- function(x) sum(exp(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the fact that most base functions are already vectorized :

1) create a dummy vector

```r
1:10
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

2) apply your function on that vector, you get vectorized result

```r
exp(1:10)
#>  [1]     2.718282     7.389056    20.085537    54.598150   148.413159
#>  [6]   403.428793  1096.633158  2980.957987  8103.083928 22026.465795
```

3) Sum that vector

```r
sum(exp(1:10))
#> [1] 34843.77
```

4) Write your function to gain (a little) time

```r
my_fun <- function(x){sum(exp(x))}
my_fun(1:10)
#> [1] 34843.77
```